# On what Oracle distribution is the 64-bit oracle.dataaccess.dll is found?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net

I would like to know on what oracle distribution is the 64-bit oracle.dataaccess.dll is found.  So far I have downloaded 64-bit [Oracle10g Release 2 ODAC for Windows x64   ODAC10203x64.zip](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html) and [Oracle Database 11g Release 1 (11.1.0.7.0) 
for Microsoft Windows Server 2008 x64](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/111070-win64-2008soft-084715.html?ssSourceSiteId=otncn) but the dll is not present.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why are you looking for that DLL in particular?

Comment: so that .NET can connect to an oracle database

Comment: Are you looking for `Oracle 11g Release 2 ODAC 11.2.0.1.2 with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio` http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-101290.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the download on OTN:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

It's also available on metallink: download the latest 64-bit 11.2 database patchset.

Christian Shay

Oracle

Answer (score 0):

From what i know, the 64bit ODAC 11g can be downloaded through oracle metalink. The 64 bit version is a separate installer from the 32bit version (which can be downloaded freely). You need to have a metalink account to login.